# Bison shift/reduce and reduce/reduce conflict

Tags: bison, shift-reduce-conflict, reduce-reduce-conflict

OK, I have tried to rewrite this Bison grammar three times now and keep running into shift/reduce and reduce/reduce conflicts.  The Syntax that I am trying to parse is as follows.  The items in the {...} are for one or the other.  The items i n the [...] are optional.

```
CONSTANT constant-name constant-class 
    constant-class = { EQUALS expression numeric-options } 
                     { EQUALS STRING string string-options } 
    numeric-options = [ PREFIX prefix-string ] 
                      [ TAG tag-string ]  
                      [ COUNTER #local-name ]
                      [ TYPENAME type-name ] ; 
    string-options = [ PREFIX prefix-string ] 
                     [ TAG tag-string ] ; 

CONSTANT (constant-name,...) EQUALS expression 
                 [ INCREMENT expression ] 
                 [ PREFIX prefix-string ] 
                 [ TAG tag-string ] 
                 [ COUNTER #local-name ] 
                 [ TYPENAME type-name ]; 

CONSTANT  constant-name EQUALS expression, 
                . 
                . 
                . 
 ;

CONSTANT  (constant-name,...) EQUALS expression, 
                . 
                . 
                . 
 ;
```

I'm having issues with the getting the last three to all work.  I can get any one of them to work, but not all 4 of them.  I right now have one shift/reduce and one reduce/reduce conflict.  The grammar I have is as follows:

```
constant
    : SDL_K_CONSTANT constant_style ';'
    ;

constant_style
    : constant_name constant_class
    | constant_list
    | constant_set
    ;

constant_name
    : sdl_name
    ;

constant_class
    : SDL_K_EQUALS sdl_decimal
    | SDL_K_EQUALS SDL_K_STRING sdl_string
    ;

constant_names
    : constant_name
    | constant_names ',' constant_name
    | '(' constant_names ')'
    ;

names_equal
    : constant_names SDL_K_EQUALS sdl_decimal
    ;

constant_list
    : names_equal
    ;

constant_set
    : names_equal
    | constant_set ',' names_equal
    ;
```

I think the names are self documenting (at least you should be able to understand the types).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I have a feeling that I either simplified too much or not enough.

NOTE: I figured out how to edit my post and removed the options and changed SDL_K_COMMA and SDL_K_SEMI to ',' and ';', respectively.

Thanks.

Here are some examples that should parse:

```
CONSTANT block_node_size EQUALS 24;
CONSTANT Strcon EQUALS STRING "This is a string constant" PREFIX Jg$ 
#block_size = 24;
CONSTANT block_node_size EQUALS #block_size;
CONSTANT 
    xyz EQUALS 10, 
    alpha EQUALS 0, 
    noname EQUALS 63;
CONSTANT
    (zyx, nameless) EQUALS 10,
    (beta) EQUALS 1,
    gamma EQUALS 42;
CONSTANT ( 
    bits, 
    bytes, 
    words, 
    longs, 
    quads, 
    octas 
    ) EQUALS 0 INCREMENT 1 PREFIX ctx$;
CONSTANT 
    (bad_block,bad_data,,,, 
    overlay,rewrite) EQUALS 0 INCREMENT 4;
CONSTANT (pli,c,bliss,macro) 
    EQUALS 4 INCREMENT 4 PREFIX lang$ 
    COUNTER #lang;
CONSTANT (basic,pascal,fortran) 
    EQUALS #lang + 4 INCREMENT 4 PREFIX lang$;
```

I hope this helps.

BTW: Here is the EBNF (sort of) for this:

```
/*
 * Define the CONSTANT construct (Left out Expression).
 */
Str                 ::= "\"" Printable* "\""
Name                ::= "$" | "_" | [A-Za-z] ("$" | "_" | [A-Z0-9a-z])*
Names               ::= Name | ("(" Name ("," Name )* ")")
Constant_class      ::= "EQUALS" (Expression Numeric_options | "STRING" Str 
                        String_options)
String_options      ::= Prefix? Tag?
Numeric_options     ::= String_options Counter? Typename? Radix?
Increment_options   ::= Increment? Numeric_options
Constant_list       ::= Names "EQUALS" Expression Increment_options
Constant_set        ::= Names Equals Expression
                        ("," Names "EQUALS" Expression)*
Constant            ::= "CONSTANT" (Name Constant_class | Constant_list | 
                        Constant_set) ";"?
Prefix              ::= "PREFIX" Str
Tag                 ::= "TAG" Str
Radix               ::= "RADIX" ("DEC" | "OCT" | "HEX")
Counter             ::= "COUNTER" Variable
Increment           ::= "INCREMENT" Expression
Typename            ::= "TYPENAME" Name
```

I think that's about it.

Comment: BTW: all the *_options and associated grammars can be removed and still demonstrate the issue (it is cleaner to deal with).  I should have removed them.  Sorry.

Comment: You could make the grammar much more readable (for me, anyway) by using `','` instead of `SDK_K_COMMA` (as an example).

Comment: Sorry about that.  I figured out how to edit my own post.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back to you. I hope it's helpful. (What's the language you are actually trying to parse, out of curiosity? Do you have some reference?)

Comment: The language is called Structure Definition Language (SDL).  It is something developed at Digital Equipment Corporation to generate program definitions for multiple programming languages.  Here is a link to the CONSTANT format for this  [link](http://kednos.com/pli/sdlext/DOC/SDL/4665profile_007.html#const_form) (NOTE: There is a bug/ambiguity in the documentation but examples in the document that may be a bit clearer).  I'll add more details to your response below.

Comment: OK, I put together a functioning bison/flex grammar as best I could, triangulating the various documents and making guesses at strategic points where the various documents contradict each other or underspecify. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little hard for me to understand what you are actually trying to do, so I've made some assumptions and provided some alternatives below. I hope that it comes close.

The basic issue is ambiguity in your grammar specifications. One of these might just be a mistake: according to your templates, the left-hand hand side of the `EQUAL` seems to be either a single `name` or a comma-separated list of `name`s surrounded by parentheses. However, your grammar allows a comma-separated list of `name`s, with the possibility that the first (or only) item in the list could be a parenthesized lists of names:

```
constant_names
    : constant_name
    | constant_names ',' constant_name
    | '(' constant_names ')
```

That will match `a`, `a, b`, `(a, b)`, `(a, b), c` and `(a, b), c, d`. BUt I think only the first and third of those are actually intended.

In any event, you have two productions:

```
constant_style
    : constant_name constant_class
    | constant_list
```

For the first one, we have:

```
constant_class
    : SDL_K_EQUALS sdl_decimal
```

while for the second, we have:

```
constant_list: names_equal
names_equal
    : constant_names SDL_K_EQUALS sdl_decimal
```

Since `constant_name` can match a single `name`, there are two different ways to match `answer = 42`, which will inevitably lead to a parsing conflict.

But there's yet another possible parse for `answer = 42`:

```
constant_set
    : names_equal
```

So let's start by simplifying all that stuff, and then we can maybe get back to what (might be) your original goal. The idea is to factor everything which is syntactically similar:

```
constant-stmt  : "CONSTANT" clause-list ';'
clause-list    : clause | clause-list ',' clause
clause         : left-hand-side "EQUALS" right-hand-side
left-hand-side : name | '(' name-list ')'
name-list      : name | name-list ',' name
right-hand-side: expression   /* See below */
```

I hope that is all simple enough to understand.

But we can see from the original that (at least in certain circumstances), there are many more options for `right-hand-side` than appear in the above snippet. It would be trivial to just add the other syntaxes to `right-hand-side`. However, it appears that the intention is that these extra options are only available in the case that there is a single clause. In that case, we could do something like this:

```
constant-stmt  : "CONSTANT" constant-body ';'
constant-body  : complex-clause | clause-list
clause-list    : clause | clause-list ',' clause
clause         : left-hand-side "EQUALS" right-hand-side
right-hand-side: expression
complex-clause : left-hand-side "EQUALS" complex-rhs
complex-rhs    : expression numeric-options
               | "STRING" string-literal string-options
```

But unfortunately, that is back to being ambiguous because `numeric-options` might be empty, so `expression` will match both `right-hand-side` and `complex-right-hand-side`.

In practice, this ambiguity doesn't matter. There is no semantic difference between the declaration `name EQUALS expression` as the only declaration in a `CONSTANT` declaration or as one of a list of such declarations. So one possibility is to just ignore the resulting reduce/reduce conflict, possibly by putting `%expect 1` into the file. But that's not very pleasant really. So we will try to eliminate the problem.

One way would be to insist that the first `complex-rhs` have at least one `numeric-option`. But that's going to be truly annoying. First, we'd have to create yet another clause type -- `first-complex-clause` or some such -- and second, we'd have to write out the requirement that at least one option be present.

As a simpler alternative, we can just require that a `clause-list` have at least two `clause`s, rather than just one. Since every `clause` can also match `complex-clause`, the restriction on `clause-list` will not reject any valid `clause`. So that gives us the very minor change:

```
constant-body  : complex-clause | clause-list
clause-list    : clause ',' clause | clause-list ',' clause
```

---

#### Addendum

With a more precise description of the intended syntax (although it is still missing some details), I modified the above grammar to attempt to parse the full language. The basic principle remains intact: a definition consists of a single `complex-clause` (which includes the simple clause case), or a list of at least two simple `clause`s. The only difference is the way the two clause types are defined.

I also fixed the name-list production so that individual names can be omitted (eg. `(bad_block,bad_data,,,,overlay,rewrite)`). As indicated in the guide, the list must contain at least one name, which slightly complicates the grammar.

I added the options from the guide (but not the extra ones in the EBNF). I did not try to deal with omitted semicolons, which don't seem to be allowed in the guide although there is an example of a declaration without a trailing semicolon. (That could be a typo.) I added the definition of `expression`, to the best of my understanding.

I also added the local-name assignment statement because it was in the test file and it was easy.

Here's the grammar:

```
definition      : %empty
                | definition constant-defn
                | definition local-assign
local-assign    : LOCAL_NAME '=' expression ';'
constant-defn   : "CONSTANT" constant-body ';'
constant-body   : complex-clause | clause-list
clause-list     : clause ',' clause | clause-list ',' clause
clause          : name "EQUALS" expression
                | name-list "EQUALS" expression
complex-clause  : name "EQUALS" expression numeric-options
                | name-list "EQUALS" expression list-options
                | name "EQUALS" "STRING" string-literal string-options
                | name-list "EQUALS" "STRING" string-literal string-options
name-list       : '(' names ')'
names           : optional-commas name | names ',' name | names ','
optional-commas : %empty | optional-commas ',' 
string-options  : prefix-option tag-option
numeric-options : string-options counter-option typename-option
list-options    : increment-option numeric-options
increment-option: %empty | "INCREMENT" expression
prefix-option   : %empty | "PREFIX" prefix-name
tag-option      : %empty | "TAG" tag-name
counter-option  : %empty | "COUNTER" LOCAL_NAME
typename-option : %empty | "TYPENAME" name

expression      : '-' expression %prec UNOP
                | expression '*' expression
                | expression '/' expression
                | expression '+' expression
                | expression '-' expression
                | expression '@' expression
                | expression '&' expression
                | expression '!' expression
                | '(' expression ')'
                | INTEGER
                | IDENT
                | LOCAL_NAME
name            : IDENT | QUOTED_IDENT
prefix-name     : IDENT | QUOTED_NULL | QUOTED_IDENT
tag-name        : IDENT | QUOTED_NULL | QUOTED_IDENT | QUOTED_TAG
string-literal  : QUOTED_NULL | QUOTED_IDENT | QUOTED_TAG | QUOTED_STRING
```

You'll see that I added a discrimination of various types of quoted strings so that it is possible to deal with (most of) the different contexts in which quoted strings may appear. I didn't include the use of quoted strings of up to 4 characters as integer constants, as indicated in the guide, because I didn't notice it in time, and also because I couldn't figure out with a brief reading whether the intent is to allow constants in expressions whose names must be quoted (because the name conflicts with a keyword); in that case, it seems to me that there is an ambiguity with a quoted name with four or fewer characters.

In case it's not obvious how the discrimination works (and it probably isn't), here's the accompanying flex definition:

```
id   [[:alpha:]$_][[:alnum:]$_]*

%%

[[:space:]]+         ;

CONSTANT             { return K_CONSTANT; }
COUNTER              { return K_COUNTER; }
EQUALS               { return K_EQUALS; }
INCREMENT            { return K_INCREMENT; }
PREFIX               { return K_PREFIX; }
STRING               { return K_STRING; }
TAG                  { return K_TAG; }
TYPENAME             { return K_TYPENAME; }

[#]{id}              { yylval.str = strndup(yytext, yyleng); return LOCAL_NAME; }
{id}                 { yylval.str = strndup(yytext, yyleng); return IDENT; }
["]{id}["]           { yylval.str = strndup(yytext+1, yyleng-2); return QUOTED_IDENT; }

["]["]               { yylval.str = strndup(yytext+1, yyleng-2); return QUOTED_NULL; }
["][[:alnum:]$_]+["] { yylval.str = strndup(yytext+1, yyleng-2); return QUOTED_TAG; }
["][[:print:]]+["]   { yylval.str = strndup(yytext+1, yyleng-2); return QUOTED_STRING; }

[[:digit:]]+         { yylval.dec = strtoul(yytext, 0, 0); return INTEGER; }
.                    { return *yytext; }
```

I did a rather inadequate test by running it with the definitions at the end of the OP (although I added a trailing `;` in the second line). I didn't actually check that the parse tree was correct, but it certainly does all pass through the parser.

Comment: I can see the ambiguity, and it is that which I have been unable to define away.  Here are actual examples that should be able to be parsed:

Comment: BTW: options are independently optional.

Comment: @jonBelanger: I think my interpretation is correct, then. If you have a simple declaration, `CONSTANT name EQUALS 3`, the two possible parses have identical semantics. The EBNF does not match the document in a couple of places; the fact that it doesn't allow names to be omitted from name lists (so that `(foo,,,,bar)` is legal) is clearly wrong; the fact that the semicolon is optional is not indicated anywhere in the document narrative that I can see, but is certainly possible. Anyway, the basic outline in my answer seems to me to be applicable. I might try to fix some details later.

Comment: This is fantastic.  I decided to look at this a bit differently.  If I use start states in flex, I can get the kinds of parsing I'm looking for.  Once of the things I did was to allow 2 types of names; one that is just a name and one that is a list of one or more names separated by commas `,` and within parentheses '(...)`.  I also added parsing that will look at where a comma `,` is locate, to detect a CONSTANT with a comma separated `<name> EQUALS <expr>, ...;`.  It appears to be working, but I'm having some issues with bison throwing `unexpected 'blah', using default rule (" ").` errors.

Comment: @jonbelanger: well, good luck. Playing games like that in the lexer is almost never my first choice. Fwiw, the code I pasted does work (afaik) and you're more than welcome to use it.

Comment: If I had not spent the entire day re-arranging things, I would have jumped on your solution.  If my current attempt does not work out, I'll revert to what I had and make the updates you indicated.

Comment: In the end, I needed to do what you suggested above, with one change.  In the flex portion of the code, a single name and a list of names is captured differently, so I don't need to figure them out in the parser and keep track of all kinds of other items.  Once the parser has collected all it's information, it will then go through and do all the right things, based on whether it has a single name or list of names.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @JonBelanger: Cool. Glad it was of use. (It's almost always tempting to put too much parsing logic in the lexer. And it's almost always a pain to rip it out and add it to the parser where it belongs, when you later realise that it's not going to work. In that light, you might want to think about whether you are correctly handling comments inside a name list. But if what you have works for you, great!)

Comment: As for the comments, I get them out just fine.  Since the name is a list of names and comments are always terminated on a new-line, it is relatively easy to parse out the comment (it goes from the comment character to the new-line, if the comment character is present).  Thanks for all your help.  I have a new question about Bison for you, but I think it'll be an easy one for you to answer.